# mongodb with rails, find by id in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, select, find, bson

I can fetch an element by BSON id from Mongodb with

```
db.my_collection.find({_id: ObjectId("567bc95ab62c732243123450")})
```

And it works. But how can I get an array of ids? something like

```
db.my_collection.find({_id: [ObjectId("567bc95ab62c732243123450"])})
```

I tried different ways, as suggested on mongodb's website, but the interactive shell complained for syntax.

**EDIT:**

Found a problem:

it should be

```
db.my_collections.find({_id: { $in : [ObjectId("567bc95ab62c732243123450")]}})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And in Rails:

```
MyCollection.find({'_id' => { "$in" => collection_ids}})
```